# ReactNative: Disable the Activity Indicator only after navigation to a new page is completed

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, activity-indicator, stack-navigator

I'm new to React Native. I have coded a Login page and Profile page.

On Login.js page I have state:

```
this.state = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  authenticating: false,
}
```

Once you hit the Login button after entering correct details, loginUser function gets executed:

```
loginUser = (email, password) => {
this.setState({ authenticating: true });
try {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
      this.setState({ authenticating: false });
    });
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error.toString());
  }
}
```

Below is my render function:

```
renderCurrentState() {
if (this.state.authenticating) {
  return (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
    </View>
  )
}

return (
  <View>
    <Input
      placeholder='Enter your Email...'
      label='Email'
      onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
      value={this.state.email}
    />
    <Input
      placeholder='Enter your Password...'
      label='Password'
      secureTextEntry
      onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
      value={this.state.password}
    />
    <Button
      onPress={() => this.loginUser(this.state.email, this.state.password)}
    >Log in</Button>

    <Button
      onPress={() => this.signUpUser(this.state.email, this.state.password)}
    >Sign upp</Button>

  </View>
)
}
```

The problem is once I hit the login button, it starts showing the activity indicator but just before showing the 'Profile' page it shows the 'Login' page once again for few milliseconds which I don't want.

Any help on this. I dont want to put a setTimeOut delay solution like this:

```
setTimeout(()=>{  this.setState({ authenticating: false }) }, 100)
```

If someone can provide me a code for this. It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-navigation now has lifecycle hooks. You can wait for current screen to blur so that you know the transition has completed.

```
  navigateAsync = (routeName) => {
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      const subscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('didBlur', () => {
        subscription.remove();
        resolve();
      });
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName);
    return promise;
  };
```

And then you can just call

```
this.navigateAsync('Profile').then(() => {
  this.setState({ authenticating: false });
})
```

See https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/11

Comment: Thank You Sebastien. It is working!! Can you please give me a little explanation of the code. Can I put "this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName);" at the starting of navigateAsync function ?

Comment: Not sure but you can probably. It is probably more risky as if there is no animation the onBlur may fire before you add the listener. What do you want me to explain particularly?

Comment: Okay, Thanks I understood.